# Create animation clips programatically

Tags: unity, c#, assets

I am messing around with Unity and the [LPC Spritesheet Collection](https://opengameart.org/content/lpc-collection).

The LPC sprites are a set of artworks all of the same size and the same amount of animations. I can create animations for it no problem, when I do it manually.

My issue is: LPC has a lot of different character bodies (skin colors, different races), since they are of the same size and have the same animations in the same way, I was trying to create an `AssetPostProcessor` extension that would create the animations automatically when I import a LPC image into my project.

I am already able to slice the spritesheets correctly with [this](https://github.com/bitcula/Universal-LPC-Spritesheet-Unity-Importer) Script I found, and I can create and save the animation clips based on the spritesheets. The clips have the correct length and configuration, but the sprites for each frame seem to be empty! Take a look at the image below...

[image]

This is the piece of code that generates the animations from the sprite meta datas:

```
    for (int col = 0; col < m_ColCount; ++col)
    {
        SpriteMetaData meta = new SpriteMetaData();
        meta.rect = new Rect(col * LPC_SPRITE_SIZE, row * LPC_SPRITE_SIZE, LPC_SPRITE_SIZE, LPC_SPRITE_SIZE);

// I skipped some code for renaming and checking for empty sprite frames for brevity...

EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = new EditorCurveBinding();
        spriteBinding.type = typeof(SpriteRenderer);
        spriteBinding.path = "";
        spriteBinding.propertyName = "m_Sprite";

    ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] spriteKeyFrames = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe[currentLoops.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLoops.Count; i++)
    {
        spriteKeyFrames[i] = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe();
        spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i;
        spriteKeyFrames[i].value = currentLoops[i];
    }

    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    clip.name = animState.ToString();
    clip.frameRate = currentLoops.Count;

    AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve(clip, spriteBinding, spriteKeyFrames);

    if(!changesToSave.ContainsKey("Assets/Sprites/" + clip.name + ".anim"))
        changesToSave.Add("Assets/Sprites/" + clip.name + ".anim", clip);

    Debug.Log("Added " + clip.name);
}
TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
textureImporter.spritesheet = metas.ToArray();
```

And I am saving the sprites in the `OnPostProcessSprites` callback like this:

```
Debug.Log("Sliced Sprites: " + sprites.Length);

foreach (var key in changesToSave.Keys)
{
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(changesToSave[key], key);
}

var textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
Debug.Log(textureImporter.spritesheet.Length);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

Comment: If there's no difference between the animation data for each of these sets of sprites, then you might not want to create new animations at all. Setting up a script to always run the same animation, but swap the sprites displayed, would likely be more efficient.

Comment: @DMGregory hmmm sounds interesting, but how would that work? I know I can set the sprite in the spriterenderer component, but how would I do that with a sliced spritesheet?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your insight, I figured it out and implemented my own sprite swapper for this case!

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to something like "How do I animate many sets of sprites with the same animation?" And add the solution you developed as an Answer.